# How do I complete a Finishing Move?

Tags: chroma-squad

I played through the whole tutorial, and in there, it teaches you how to do a finishing move on a boss. Well, I must not have been paying as much attention as I thought, because now I am trying to do them and am failing miserably.

How do I do a Finishing Move properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goal can be accomplished with the pillar of sentai moves: Teamwork!

You need to have all five of your squad ready to act, so this is a full turn move.  Move four of them next to the boss (diagonals are okay), and hit the Teamwork star.  They'll get a little yellow box under them, and they'll do a little bit of a pose.

Then, move your last team member next to the boss and just attack as usual.  With four members waiting in Teamwork, you'll do a huge Finishing Move!

One warning: If your Finishing Move doesn't actually finish the boss, you'll lose some audience for using it too soon.  So be careful!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I believe that your team also has to Chromatize before they can perform a Finishing Move.